# Incomplete output from xcodebuild parallelize build

Tags: xcodebuild

I have been having trouble with this xcodebuild problem for a long while and have done a lot of research on this but not being able to find a solution...

The problem is we have a Xcode scheme, that use parallel build (parallelizeBuildables="YES"). When this scheme is built by xcodebuild (from CI server agent), the log output from xcodebuild is INCOMPLETE. I have done a lot of testing/debugging and believe this is a xcodebuild problem. Because when I fired up xcodebuild from a login session, the result is the same. xcodebuild log output will be incomplete. This was really annoying as the error and failure points cannot be shown in our CI server.

Curiously I have read tons of posts but didn't find any one finding this problem. I wondered why? Is it because others didn't use parallelize build? Definitely we want to use parallelize build but if turning off it is the only solution to this problem, we have to do it.

So my questions are:
1. Did anyone find the same problem?
2. Is there a way to turn off parallelize build (overriding the setting in the scheme) from xcodebuild command line?

Any help and discussion is greatly appreciated.

P.S. I have been having this problem since early Xcode 4.0 or 4.1 till now with Xcode 4.6